# Почему в браузере Chrome не работает защишённое соединение?а http -работает. Мозила работает

Tags: google-chrome, https

Столкнулся с проблемой на компе у друга.
Почему в браузере Chrome не работает защишённое соединение?а http -работает. Мозила работает во всех типах соединений.
Ошибка сертификата.

Я погуглил. менял дату, как советовалось, но всёравно.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно подделка сертификата. Подставной сертификат выпущен удостоверяющим центром, который не включен в список доверенных. Подделывать могут провайдер, вирус или антивирус

Comment: @"Dmitry Kozlov" Прикол в том, что это только что переустановленная винда и я сам ничего ещё не успел установить

Comment: возможно импорт при установке хрома. возможно настройки иешки, с которой взял настройки - хром. а вообще забавный случай, на новой винде и в хроме не работает хттпс %)